# How to convert Pandas group by to dictionary and excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the following format :

```
"owners_data": [
{
  "owner_id":1,
  "in_hours": 30,
  "us_hours": 1,
  "client_id": "139",
  "in_revenue": 0,
  "in_te_cost": 0,
  "project_id": "100336",
},
{
  "owner_id":1,
  "in_hours": 30,
  "us_hours": 1,
  "client_id": "139",
  "in_revenue": 0,
  "in_te_cost": 0,
  "project_id": "100337",
},
{
  "owner_id":1,
  "in_hours": 30,
  "us_hours": 1,
  "client_id": "139",
  "in_revenue": 0,
  "in_te_cost": 0,
  "project_id": "100338",
},
{
  "owner_id":2,
  "in_hours": 30,
  "us_hours": 1,
  "client_id": "129",
  "in_revenue": 0,
  "in_te_cost": 0,
  "project_id": "100339",
},
{
  "owner_id":2,
  "in_hours": 30,
  "us_hours": 1,
  "client_id": "149",
  "in_revenue": 0,
  "in_te_cost": 0,
  "project_id": "100343",
}
```

]

That is, the same owner can have multiple clients, and each client has multiple projects. Now I need to display this data in an excel sheet which looks like the following

[image]

That is by client ID, and by project ID. So I am trying to group my data, which is a list of dictionaries by client ID and then by project ID using `pandas` groupby and have the following code:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_records(acc_owner_data)
dataframe_groupby = dataframe.groupby(['owner_id','client_id','project_id'])
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(dataframe_groupby)
exit()
```

Here I am getting `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x114c20f40>` and I use `print(dataframe_groupby.count())`I get the following:

```
                               in_hours  us_hours  in_revenue  in_te_cost
owner_id client_id project_id                                            
1        139       100336             1         1           1           1
                   100337             1         1           1           1
                   100338             1         1           1           1
2        129       100339             1         1           1           1
         149       100343             1         1           1           0
```

This is not correct as it shows 1 as the value for all the columns. How can I use `groupby` here to group it correctly and how can I convert this to a multi-dimensional array so as the owner ID, client ID, and project ID as keys so that I can loop through it and create an excel file?

Also, if there is any other better method other than using `pandas`, please suggest.

Comment: I am not sure what is your expected output. Does `sum()` instead of `count()` help? 
BTW, You do not have to loop over an array, try `dataframe.to_excel()` function first.

Comment: if you want to loop then simply use directly `for`-loop like `for parameters, data in dataframe_groupby: ...`

Comment: I would agree with @Jacob in using something like `group = df.groupby(by=['owner_id','client_id','project_id']).sum()`. The column that shows 1 is _only_ `us_hours` and the others, just show 0. In your example those fields `sum` to 0 if we group them with all the three factors you mention. Would your problem perhaps be in writing to excel with the proper headings?